# rescue_from in functional / integration tests in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some issues with functional tests not properly handeling exceptions raised while processing an action.  Any time an action raises an error, it gets propagated all the way through to the functional test, instead of being caught and resulting in a render of the default exception page.

I have the following configurations set in config/environments/test.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, wish I knew the answer. Everyone says testing infrastructure is great in Rails, that has not been my experience.